# RabbitVCS installation not working

Tags: rabbitvcs

I have followed this instructions and installed through command line. 
[Rabbit VCS  installation link](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/ubuntu)   While installing it .  Thunar is not installed.it showed

```
E: Unable to locate package rabbitvcs-thunar
```

other things,
cli, gedit, nautilus, nautilus3 all installed.

And I can't find any new icon to open RabbitVCS and also i restarted my machine to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing  Rabbit VCS,you have to reboot your ubuntu, lubuntu,xubuntu, than you can't find any new icon on the applications menu to start it. Instead of it. you can able to find the SVN on your  Nautilus File manager.

Just open your  file manager and move to any directory and right click there.

The RabbitVCS options are there for you.

If Thunar is not installed on your machine. No Problem it will work on your machine itself. So linux core have packages for the Thunar.

If you need editor, you can install  gedit,otherwise left it without installing it.